# How do I groupby a dynamic list of column names?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to modify some code to become more flexible.

Here is the woking code:

```
df_out = pdf.set_index('TTF_WEEKS').groupby(['PRODUCT','COMMODITY_CODE','FISCAL_WEEK_ENDDATE'], group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.reindex(np.arange(pdf.TTF_WEEKS.min(),pdf.TTF_WEEKS.max()+1)))
```

I would like to make it so that the column names are not hard coded.  I got the set_index piece solved since it's just a single string, but not sure how to handle the group by.

Here is my partial solution:

```
col_cnt = len(list(pdf.columns.values))

df_out = pdf.set_index(pdf.columns[col_cnt-1]).groupby(['PRODUCT','COMMODITY_CODE','FISCAL_WEEK_ENDDATE'], group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.reindex(np.arange(pdf.TTF_WEEKS.min(),pdf.TTF_WEEKS.max()+1)))
```

I'm thinking that I would want some sort of join (pseudo code)

```
for i in range(col_cnt-2):
    join( pdf.columns[i],',')
```

How would I go about this?

Edit: OK, so I got closer, but now getting an error:

```
col_grp = "'" + "','".join(map(str, list(pdf.columns.values)[:col_cnt-2])) + "'"
df_out = pdf.set_index(pdf.columns[col_cnt-2]).groupby([col_grp], group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.reindex(np.arange(pdf.TTF_WEEKS.min(),pdf.TTF_WEEKS.max()+1)))
```

Gives an error:

> KeyError: "'PRODUCT','COMMODITY_CODE','FISCAL_WEEK_ENDDATE'"

Comment: sounds like you need resample or asfreq

Answer (score 1):

From the KeyError, I think you're building a string that consists of `'PRODUCT','COMMODITY_CODE','FISCAL_WEEK_ENDDATE'`. What you really need is for `col_grp` to contain a list of strings.

Try replacing

```
col_grp = "'" + "','".join(map(str, list(pdf.columns.values)[:col_cnt-2])) + "'"
```

With

```
col_grp = df.columns.tolist()
```

Comment: Yes this is perfect.  I just need to apply a filter to col_grp so it doesn't include the last 2 columns and now it's working perfectly.  Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelMelillo, awesome!